# Find longest match number on another table

Tags: sqlite

Given I have two tables - routes and country_codes.
Table routes contains column `prefix` which I want to match to the longest value found in table country_codes column `code`

The objective is to find the country name of each route.

The data structure I have

```
CREATE TABLE routes(
   prefix   INTEGER  NOT NULL,
   supplier VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
);
```

table routes

```
prefix      supplier
1876        att
1787        att
1           att
81          bt
8150        bt
8170        bt
8180        bt
8190        bt
82          verizon
821         verizon
84          att
84120       att
84121       att
84122       att
84123       att
84124       att
84125       att
85248       verizon
85249       verizon
85251       verizon


CREATE TABLE country_codes (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    country VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    code INTEGER
);
```

table country_codes

```
167 American Samoa              1684
170 Anguilla                    1264
173 Antigua and Barbuda         1268
181 Bahamas                     1242
184 Barbados                    1246
189 Bermuda                     1441
195 British Virgin Islands      1284
205 Cayman Islands              1345
225 Dominica                    1767
226 Dominican Republic          1809
227 Dominican Republic          1829
228 Dominican Republic          1849
251 Grenada                     1473
253 Guam                        1671
273 Jamaica                     1876
310 Montserrat                  1664
326 Northern Mariana Islands    1670
340 Puerto Rico                 1787
341 Puerto Rico                 1939
350 Saint Kitts and Nevis       1869
351 Saint Lucia                 1758
354 Saint Vincent and the Grenadines    1784
364 Sint Maarten                1721
389 Trinidad and Tobago         1868
393 Turks and Caicos Islands    1649
399 United States               1
401 US Virgin Islands           1340
274 Japan                       81
370 South Korea                 82
405 Vietnam                     84
201 Cambodia                    855
261 Hong Kong                   852
282 Laos                        856
291 Macau                       853
325 North Korea                 850
```

So I want to query table `routes` to give me result prefix, country

results I am looking for

```
prefix      country
1876        Jamaica
1787        Puerto Rico
1           United States
81          Japan
8150        Japan
8170        Japan
8180        Japan
8190        Japan
82          South Korea
821         South Korea
84          Vietnam
84120       Vietnam
84121       Vietnam
84122       Vietnam
84123       Vietnam
84124       Vietnam
84125       Vietnam
85248       Hong Kong
85249       Hong Kong
85251       Hong Kong
```

What sql query can i use to do this?

The complication its not a straight match that can be done with a join.
Its longest match needs to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must check the `prefix` from `routes` and all of its substrings and use `COALESCE()` until you get the row from `country_codes`

```
SELECT 
  r.prefix,
  COALESCE(
    (SELECT country FROM country_codes c WHERE c.code = r.prefix), 
    (SELECT country FROM country_codes c WHERE c.code = SUBSTR(r.prefix, 1, 4)),
    (SELECT country FROM country_codes c WHERE c.code = SUBSTR(r.prefix, 1, 3)),
    (SELECT country FROM country_codes c WHERE c.code = SUBSTR(r.prefix, 1, 2)),
    (SELECT country FROM country_codes c WHERE c.code = SUBSTR(r.prefix, 1, 1))
  ) AS country
FROM routes AS r;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a `JOIN` to get all the matches.  For each prefix, order the matches according to the length of the country code with a window function.   Then keep only the first row for each prefix.

```sql
SELECT prefix
     , country
  FROM
   (
       SELECT prefix
            , country
            , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY prefix ORDER BY length(code) DESC) AS row_number
         FROM routes 
    LEFT JOIN country_codes 
           ON prefix LIKE code || '%'
   )
 WHERE row_number = 1
;
```